# How to Insert xml data into SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server

How to import below XML data into SQL Server table with three columns?

```
<dataset> 
 <metadata>
  <item name="NAME_LAST" type="xs:string" length="62" /> 
  <item name="NAME_FIRST" type="xs:string" length="62" /> 
  <item name="NAME_MIDDLE" type="xs:string" length="32" />
 </metadata>
<data>
<row>
 <value>SMITH</value> 
 <value>MARY</value> 
 <value>N</value> 
</row>
<row>
 <value>SMITH2</value> 
 <value>MARY2</value> 
 <value>N2</value> 
</row>
</data>
</dataset>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, try looking here first: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316005

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<dataset> 
 <metadata>
  <item name="NAME_LAST" type="xs:string" length="62" /> 
  <item name="NAME_FIRST" type="xs:string" length="62" /> 
  <item name="NAME_MIDDLE" type="xs:string" length="32" />
 </metadata>
<data>
<row>
 <value>SMITH</value> 
 <value>MARY</value> 
 <value>N</value> 
</row>
<row>
 <value>SMITH2</value> 
 <value>MARY2</value> 
 <value>N2</value> 
</row>
</data>
</dataset>'

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(ColName, ColFirstName, ColOther)
   SELECT
      Name = XCol.value('(value)[1]','varchar(25)'),
      FirstName = XCol.value('(value)[2]','varchar(25)'),
      OtherValue = XCol.value('(value)[3]','varchar(25)')
   FROM 
      @input.nodes('/dataset/data/row') AS XTbl(XCol)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Insert XML Data into sql Server table

Declare @retValue1 varchar(50);
Declare @XmlStr XML;
SET @XmlStr='<Customers>
 <customer>
    <ID>111589</ID>
    <FirstName>name1</FirstName>
    <LastName>Lname1</LastName>
    <Company>ABC</Company>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <FirstName>name2</FirstName>
    <LastName>Lname2</LastName>
    <Company>ABC</Company>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <ID>14567</ID>
    <FirstName>name3</FirstName>
    <LastName>Lname3</LastName>
    <Company>DEF</Company>
  </customer>
</Customers>';

@retValue='Failed';
 
INSERT INTO  [test_xmlinsert](
[id],
[firstName],
[lastName],
[company]
)
SELECT
COALESCE([Table].[Column].value('ID[1]', 'int'),0) as 'ID',
[Table].[Column].value('FirstName [1]', 'varchar(50)') as ' FirstName ',
[Table].[Column].value(' LastName[1]', 'varchar(50)') as ' LastName',
[Table].[Column].value(' Company [1]', 'varchar(50)') as ' Company'
 FROM @XmlStr.nodes('/ Customers / customer') as [Table]([Column])
IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0 )
  SET @retValue='SUCCESS';
```

Comment: I may seem silly, but first to declare the variable and set the value afterwards helped me.