# Insert XmlDocument representing FOR XML result in to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xmldocument

The code below pulls data out of a table and gives you an XmlDocument to work with:

```
using (SqlCommand command = CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('SomeEntities')";

    var xmlReader = command.ExecuteXmlReader();
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDoc.Load(xmlReader);
}
```

Giving you an XML representation of the data like this, for example:

```
<SomeEntities>
    <Entity>
        <SomeKey>123<SomeKey/>
        <SomeValue>TestString<SomeValue/>
    <Entity/>
<SomeEntities/>
```

Which is great, but is there a way to take the same XML representation of that same entire row, and insert it back in to the database?

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178107.aspx) says `FOR XML` will work with an `INSERT` but gives no example, and maybe I am using the wrong search terms but there does not seem to be much out there on this. This seems like something you would be able to do, right?

Any thoughts? Happy to provide more code or try ideas, just comment :)

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You do **not** want to store your XML into the database, but rather store the data **within** your XML back into structured tables in your database, right?

Comment: Do you need to insert XML generated on client-side (upload) or to insert XML generated by another sql statement (select..for xml)?

Comment: That's correct! The XML represents a result set from the DB. I'll add some XML to the question to make that clear.

Comment: Try the method displayed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378729/how-to-insert-xml-data-into-sql-server-table , though it doesn't use XML FOR.

Comment: The data is generated by the XML FOR query on the same table in to which I am aiming to do the insert. @Khale_Kitha I have seen various ideas like that, but am thinking there must be a more generic way to do this than define all columns and datatypes?

Comment: @GP24, thx for the example data. You'll have to think about distinguish between new data, updated data and - maybe - deletions. In SQL you might think about the `MERGE` statement...

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way to achieve this. As a matter of fact XML is **very** generic and can carry almost any kind of data in almost any structure and nestings. How should a tool know automatically what to do?

Some suggestions

1) You might create a schema (XSD) and create a `DataSet` from this. With a structurally fitting DataSet it is easy to "fill" it with your XML and then use the DataSet's features.

2) Create a stored procedure taking your XML as passed in parameter. This SP will read the data and insert them properly.

3) Write some code in C# to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo! All good ideas, and I started developing solution in C#. I am not expecting that a tool would do this. More likely that there is some poorly documented and arcane means by which the XML FOR, ELEMENTS or an XmlWriter or something might make this work in reverse.

Comment: @GP24, if you like my answer, it would be very kind to vote on it. Votes are the fuel SO is running with. And I'm addicted to rep points :-)

Comment: There you go my friend :) Thanks again for the ideas.