# insert xml data to table stored procedure sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have xml in following format

```
 <Entity>
    <name>John</name>
    <aliases><alias>Johnny</alias></aliases>
    <aliases><alias>Johnson</alias></aliases>
    </Entity>
    <Entity>
    <name>Smith</name>
    <aliases><alias>Smithy</alias></aliases>
    <aliases><alias>Schmit</alias></aliases>
    </Entity>
```

I want to insert them in table so the table should have 4 records in the example.

columns are name and alias.

```
name | alias
John | Johnny
John | Johnson
Smith| Smithy
Smith| Schmit
```

How can I achive this using cursor or something else?

What i have tried. In cursor for entity i try insert alias value,but only first alias is taken.

```
insert into  TESTTABLE
            (EntityID,Alias)
        select 
            @EntityID as EntityID,
            Alias
        from OpenXml(@ixml, '/Aliases',2)
        with (
            Alias varchar(255) '.'
        )
```

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21378920/4358787

Comment: @gaurav thank you for the reference but because the structure is <aliases><alias>  for each alias it is not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML= N'
<Entity>
    <name>John</name>
    <aliases><alias>Johnny</alias></aliases>
    <aliases><alias>Johnson</alias></aliases>
    </Entity>
    <Entity>
    <name>Smith</name>
    <aliases><alias>Smithy</alias></aliases>


     <aliases><alias>Schmit</alias></aliases>
        </Entity>'

INSERT INTO @tblTest(firstName,LastName)
        SELECT  t1.c.value('../name[1]','varchar(100)') As FirstName,t1.c.value('alias[1]','varchar(50)') as SecondName

    FROM @xml.nodes('/Entity/aliases') t1(c)
```

Comment: I will try, I have to mention that there can be any number of alias 0 to n

Comment: <aliases><alias>Smithy</alias><alias>Schmit</alias></aliases> if i have aliases with multiple alias it gets only the first one, how can also include this in the solution, otherwise this answer is correct for the example.

Comment: alias[1] can be replaced with .

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to hop back (`../name[1]`)... And it's faster to use `(somenode/text())[1]` instead of `somenode[1]`. You migtht want to [read this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242238/5089204)

Comment: @MasterYi Your *trick* to replace `alias[1]` with a simple `.` works in this very simple case, but is a dangerous and not recommended approach. The general advise is: *Be as specific as possible*

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Your XML is not *well-formed* as it is missing a root node. SQL-server can deal with XML-fragments, but other engines might fail...

You have a `1:n` related *two level* hierarchy. This is best queried with a cascade of `.nodes()`:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML= 
N'<Entity>
    <name>John</name>
    <aliases>
    <alias>Johnny</alias>
    </aliases>
    <aliases>
    <alias>Johnson</alias>
    </aliases>
</Entity>
<Entity>
    <name>Smith</name>
    <aliases>
    <alias>Smithy</alias>
    </aliases>
    <aliases>
    <alias>Schmit</alias>
    </aliases>
</Entity>'
```

--the query will use `.nodes()` to get all entities and a second time `.nodes()` to get a derived table of the aliases below each entity.

```sql
SELECT  A.ent.value('(name/text())[1]','varchar(100)') As FirstName
       ,B.ali.value('(alias/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as SecondName
FROM @xml.nodes('/Entity') A(ent)
CROSS APPLY A.ent.nodes(N'aliases') AS B(ali);
```

### UPDATE added attributes

According to one comment below I changed this a bit to reflect multiple aliases with an attribute.

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML= 
N'<Entity>
    <name>John</name>
    <aliases>
    <alias nr="1">Johnny</alias>
    <alias nr="2">OneMore</alias>
    </aliases>
    <aliases>
    <alias>Johnson</alias>
    </aliases>
</Entity>
<Entity>
    <name>Smith</name>
    <aliases>
    <alias nr="1">Smithy</alias>
    </aliases>
    <aliases>
    <alias nr="1">Schmit</alias>
    </aliases>
</Entity>' 

SELECT  A.ent.value('(name/text())[1]','varchar(100)') As FirstName
       ,B.ali.value('@nr','int') as SomeAttribute
       ,B.ali.value('text()[1]','varchar(50)') as SecondName
FROM @xml.nodes('/Entity') A(ent)
CROSS APPLY A.ent.nodes(N'aliases/alias') AS B(ali);
```

What has changed?

- `.nodes()` is diving one level deeper to `/alias`, thus repeating multiple aliases in multiple rows.
- reading the attribute with a leading `@`

Comment: Thank you! Great and simple solution. One Question what if alias would have an Attribute (like : <alias nr="1">Schmit</alias>) can i read it too the same way?